# Segmentation fault when trying to declare an array of strings

Tags: c, string, cs50

In my program, I am trying to copy each argv[i] to keyword[i], but my program fails with a segmentation fault.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])    
{
    //prototype
    string keyword = "";
    //int j;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        keyword[i] = toupper(argv[1][i]);
        printf("%i-- printing letters\n", keyword[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `string keyword = "";` you have allocated zero space for the string to be copied, and when you have a big enough space, you must also write a `nul` string terminator before you can call it a "string".

Comment: What is string? Is this C or C++?

Comment: @IshayPeled: "*`string`*" most likes comes out of "*`#include <cs50.h>`*"  and seems to a `typedef char * string;` ... :-/

Comment: @alk oh... okkkkaaaayyy (;

Comment: ...and even then, you should not be writing to a *string literal*, but allocate enough memory that you can use.

Comment: @WeatherVane It depends.. if `typedef char * string;` - yes. If `typedef char  string[];` - no.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. `string keyword = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));` won't work in your latter case.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't see this code in the question...

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's because he didn't allocate any, as has been established. See answer below.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, so the answer is making the same assumption

Comment: @EugeneSh. with my MSVC, it's only possible to guess the string length, as it has no VLAs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have observed, you initialize variable `keyword` either as an empty string or as a pointer to an empty string literal, depending on the definition of type `string`.  Either way, it is then valid to evaluate `keyword[i]` only for `i` equal to zero; any other value -- for read or write -- is out of bounds.  Furthermore, in the latter (pointer to string literal) case, you must not attempt to modify the array `keyword` points to.

Note in particular that C does not automatically expand strings if you try to access an out of bounds element. Instead, an attempt to do so produces "undefined behavior", and a common way for that to manifest in such cases is in the form of a segmentation fault.  You can view a segmentation fault as the system slapping down your program for attempting to access memory that does not belong to it.

Since you don't know *a priori* how long the argument string will be before you copy it, the most viable type for `keyword` is `char *`. I will use that type instead of `string` in what follows, for clarity.

If you indeed do want to make a copy of the argument, then by far the easiest way to do so is via the for-purpose function `strdup()`:

```
    char *keyword = strdup(argv[1]);
```

That allocates enough memory for a copy of its argument, including the terminator, copies it, and returns a pointer to the result.  You are then obligated to free the resulting memory via the `free()` function when you're done with it.  Having made a copy in that way, you can then upcase each element in place:

```
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(keyword); i < n; i++)
    {
        keyword[i] = toupper(keyword[i]);
        printf("%c-- printing letters\n", keyword[i]);
    }
```

Note, by the way, that the `printf()` format descriptor for a single character is `%c`, not `%i`.  You must use that to print the characters *as* characters, rather than their integer values.

That's one of the simplest ways to write C code for what you're trying to do, though there are many variations.  The only other one I'll offer for your consideration is to *not* copy the argument at all:

```
    char *keyword = argv[1];
```

If you initialize `keyword` that way then you do not allocate any memory or make a copy; instead, you set `keyword` to point to the same string that `argv[1]` points to.  You can modify that string in-place (though you cannot lengthen it), provided that you do not need to retain its original contents.

Before I wrap this up, I should also observe that your program does not check whether there actually is an argument.  In the event that there is not (*i.e.* `argc < 2`), `argv[1]` either contains a null pointer (`argc == 1`) or is undefined (`argc == 0`; you're unlikely ever to run into this).  Either way, your program produces undefined behavior in that case if it attempts to use `argv[1]` as if it were a pointer to a valid string.  You should test for this case first off, and terminate with a diagnostic message if no program argument is available.

Answer (score -2):

Your main problem: you're not allocating memory for your new string, (`string keyword = ""`).

In C, every size that is not known at compilation time has to be dynamically allocated during run-time.

Also, you never check for missing parameters which may crash your program.

See code below for both fixes

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <word>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int length = strlen(argv[1]);
    string keyword = malloc(length+1);

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        keyword[i] = toupper(argv[1][i]);
        printf("%i-- printing letters\n", keyword[i]);

    }
    keyword[length]=0;
    free(keyword);
}
```

Comment: `Your main problem: you're not allocating memory for your new string`......and you don't `free()` it.

Comment: This code will induce a problem if will try to access `keyword` as a string afterwards, as it is not null-terminated...

Comment: `for(int i = 0, n = strlen` should be `size_t i` not `int`. Same goes here `keyword[i] = toupper` conversion between  `char` and `int`

Comment: `string keyword = "";` very well does allocate the array. And there is also very well a way to allocate dynamically an automatic array. It's called "VLA" and supported by modern C compilers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In this example, he doesn't. Anyhow added null termination

Comment: @Olaf so? what are you trying to say?

Comment: "In C, every size that is not known at compilation time has to be dynamically allocated during run-time." - And apparently you mean `malloc` & friends with "dynamic allocation". YOu either did not read the comment carefully or missed the term "automatic".

Comment: @Olaf okay, I value your opinion

Comment: Note that in `<cs50.h>`, there is `typedef char *string;` — so there is not much in the way of array allocation in progress, and what there is makes the pointer point to an empty string literal that is probably in read-only memory and therefore (a) not big enough and (b) not modifiable.